# jQuery Form Plugin searching for page in wrong location

Tags: jquery, cherrypy, jquery-forms-plugin

I use the jQuery Form Plugin to upload files. These files are sent to my cherrypy script and back to my jQuery where the filename is then appended to my page. The system runs fine on localhost. I use webfaction as a webhost and when I try to upload a file using the form plugin I get the following error in my jQuery error log:

2013/11/24 16:41:26 [error] 26628#0: *2912993 open() "/home/mywebsite/webapps/htdocs/submit" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 5.100.131.14, server: mywebsite.webfactional.com, request: "POST /submit HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.webfactional.com", referrer: "http://mywebsite.webfactional.com/freelinreg"

Its strange that it is trying to open the submit file at "/home/mywebsite/webapps/htdocs/submit" where it does not exisit. Usually what cherrypy seems to do, based on my code below, is make '/submit' available at "http://mywebsite.webfactional.com/freelinreg/submit" or 'localhost:8080/submit' when running off my computer.

Is there someway to point the jQuery Form Plugin to look for '/submit' at "http://mywebsite.webfactional.com/freelinreg/submit" and not at "/home/mywebsite/webapps/htdocs/submit"?

class Root(object):

```
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self)
    return open('/home/joestox/webapps/freelinreg_static/index.html')

@cherrypy.expose
def submit(self, myfile):

    cherrypy.session['myfile'] = myfile
    data_name = myfile.filename

    #Send back to JQuery with Ajax
    #Put in JSON form
    data_name= json.dumps(dict(title = data_name))
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

    return data_name
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head> 
            <script type='text/javascript' src='freelinreg_static/google.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='freelinreg_static/frontend.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='freelinreg_static/malsup.js'></script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <form id="dataform" action="submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myFile"/>
            <input type="submit" id="data_submit" value="Continue"/>
        </form>                          

        </body>
    </html>
```

jQuery (frontend.js):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function () {
        $('#dataform').ajaxForm({
            success: function (data) {
                var $a_var = data['title'];
                $('body').append($a_var);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })();
});
```

Comment: It seems that you're mixing up local dirs and web paths. Do you have TMP/TEMP environment vars set correctly? Can you provide the Python error dump (you may want to run it in a console for that)?

Answer (score 0):

jwalker is correct.  You're confusing url path and physical paths.  Your cherrypy app needs a physical location on your system to store the file.  I, also, don't see you trying to save the uploaded file anywhere.

```
@cherrypy.expose
def submit(self, myfile):

    cherrypy.session['myfile'] = myfile
    data_name = myfile.filename
    upload_path = '/home/mywebsite/webapps/submit' + myfile.filename

    size = 0
    all_data = bytearray()
    while True:
        data = myfile.file.read(8192)
        all_data += data
        if not data:
            break
         size += len(data)

    saved_file=open(upload_path, 'wb') 
    saved_file.write(all_data) 
    saved_file.close()

    #Send back to JQuery with Ajax
    #Put in JSON form
    data_name= json.dumps(dict(title = data_name))

    return data_name
```

In addition it looks like you want to then be able for users to view the file.  If that's the case you're also going to need to turn on static browsing for cherrypy (If you don't have a webserver serving the static content).

```
cherrypy.config.update({'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                'tools.staticdir.dir': '/home/mywebsite/webapps/submit'
               })
```

Hope this helps!